# Unable to login to Jenkins with AD after restore

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to restore my Jenkins application onto a new ec2 server. I copied over all the .xml files within the JENKINS_HOME Directory and all the plugins but when I try to login to Jenkins I get an invalid username and credential error. I didn't change any settings in my config.xml during the copy so I'm not really for sure as to why its giving that error. I know I can disable it but by doing so it will remove all the role based authorizations that are within the config.xml and I really don't want to copy and paste them back in if I don't have to. I'm just curious if anyone else has ran into this issue before?

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: just the standard username and password doesn't work but I confirmed that it does on the working jenkins instance. I'm wondering if you have to rebind to the AD every time you restore your config.xml on a different server?